# Does Satan have a physical dwelling place on earth?

Tags: exegesis, satan, revelation

I read some articles years ago before I joined Christianity.SE and I will like us to throw more light on the content. [This article](http://www.askelm.com/prophecy/p020627.htm) authoritatively states that Satan's dwelling place is in Turkey, according to this passage:

> **Revelation 2:12-13**
>
> 12 And to the angel of the church in Pergamos write; These things
>   saith he which hath the sharp sword with two edges;
>
> 13 I know thy works, and where thou dwellest, even where Satan's seat
>   is: and thou holdest fast my name, and hast not denied my faith, even
>   in those days wherein Antipas was my faithful martyr, who was slain
>   among you, where Satan dwelleth

Is this passage really saying that Satan has or had a physical dwelling place?

Comment: Personally, I think the author of that article is reaching. But I have some off-the-wall ideas myself, so who am I to say? But I don't think that interpretation is common. I ***have*** read speculation that the Antichrist will originate from Turkey based on those verses, but not that Satan has a physical dwelling there.

Comment: This question's title is a bit off-topic, but the final question is asking for clarification on some verses, which has always been on-topic. I am not going to vtc.

Comment: New Jersey.  Definitely, New Jersey.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having been to Bergama, I can tell you this is an amazing place. An imposing temple stands at the top of a 1200 meter or so mountain. Winds blow at the top that will make you feel you will be blown into the valley below. I remember my wife driving in the valley below, and before we had even entered the town, I looked up, saw the Temple, and said - I know exactly where we are going.  It is a powerful place, and the presence of "the gods" is felt from miles away as one looks to the top of that mountain

That said, the reference in Revelation as to its position as "Satan's seat" is not that he has a chair there, but rather that it was a "capital" of sorts in Satan's empire. It was a place of power in Greek theology (and remember, Turkey was Greek at the time!) In the same way that Washington, DC is the "seat" of power in the United States, Bergama was the center of power for a particular belief system that emphasized the power of the gods to grant healing.

The Greek god [Asclepius](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asclepius) in particular drew followers from all over to experience healing.  The fact that this pagan influence was so strong would likely have led John the Revelator to say something to the effect of "Satan is very strong here," as evidenced by the deep pagan influences against which Christianity would place itself.

All this said, this does not address the question of Satan's abode.  As a created being, Satan must, by definition, have a physical presence.  Unlike God who is omnipresent, Satan is a finite being.  As such, he has a place.  When in Job, for instance, he confronts God, it says specifically that he had returned from walking the earth, and seems to indicate that there was a place in which he could come face to face with the presence of God.  Whether the earth was his home or merely on his intinerary is unclear from Scripture.

One can argue whether it is he who is cast down from heaven in Revelation 12, 18, and other places, or whether he is embodied in the "AntiChrist" or not, but this much is sure: At some point, I'll be able to pinpoint his exact location. It will be in a lake of fire where he'll spend the rest of eternity.  I'd rather not have any closer understanding of his geography than that. :)

Comment: Great answer but I'm in doubt about your fourth paragraph. "*As a created being, Satan must, by definition, have a physical presence*" Depends on type of creation. It would be difficult to assign coordinates to a non-physical entity. When we think of throwing or moving we think of physical objects. The same may not hold for non-physical, extra-dimensional, [insert a sci-fi term here] things. Satan could be face to face with God after being thrown out of heaven. The terms "*walking the earth*", "*cast down*" may be figure of speech, narrated such probably to make it understandable for humans.

Comment: @MonikaMichael the Bible says _"And no marvel; for satan himself is transformed into an angel of light..."_ He can also put on himself a human form and become concrete, like the angels of God did

Comment: @tunmisefashipe If Satan can "put on himself a human form" than he must have other forms. What are his other forms? Are they all physical in nature, like the human form? Just because he can be physical doesnt imply that he must be physical.